# How do Ruby multiple code blocks work in conjunction/when chained?

Tags: ruby

Here's a function in Ruby to find if 2 unique number in an array add up to a sum:

```
def sum_eq_n? (arr, n)
    return true if arr.empty? && n == 0

    p "first part array:" + String(arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b })
    puts "\n"

    p "first part bool:" + String(arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any?)
    puts "\n"

    p "second part:" + String(arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a + b == n } )
    puts "\n"

    result = arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }
    return result
end

#define inputs
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
n = 10

#run function
print "Result is: " + String(sum_eq_n?(l1, n))
```

I'm confused how the calculation works to produce result. As you can see I've broken the function down into a few parts to visualize this. I've researched and understand the `.reject` and the `.any?` methods individually.

However, I'm still confused on how it fits all together in the 1 liner. How are the 2 blocks evaluated in combination? I've only found examples with `.reject` with 1 code block afterwards. Is `.reject` applied to both? I also thought there might be an implicit AND in between the 2 code blocks, but I tried to add a 3rd dummy block and it failed, so at this point I'm just not really sure how it works at all.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, bu it's not very useful to check [1,5] and [5,1]. the `combination` method prevents that. `arr.uniq.combination(2).any?{|combi| combi.sum == n }`

Comment: Instead of `String(...)` consider using either interpolation, like `"first part of array: #{arr.product(...)}"` or the `.join('')` method. Ruby code tends to prefer method calls to hard casting with things like `String`.

Comment: `x { ... }.y { ... }` are simply two methods, called `x` and `y`, which each accept their own block. This form only works when `x { ... }` returns something that responds to `y`. You could rewrite your example without the method chaining as `arr1 = arr.product(arr); arr2 = arr1.reject { ... }; arr3 = arr2.any? { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret the expression via these equivalent substitutions:

```rb
# orig
arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }

# same as
pairs = arr.product(arr)
pairs.reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }

# same as
pairs = arr.product(arr)
different_pairs = pairs.reject { |a,b| a == b }
different_pairs.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }
```

Each block is an *argument* for the respective method -- one for `reject`, and one for `any?`. They are evaluated in order, and are *not* combined. The parts that make up the expression can be wrapped in parenthesis to show this:

```rb
((arr.product(arr)).reject { |a,b| a == b }).any? { |a,b| a + b == n }

# broken up lines:
(
  (
    arr.product(arr)          # pairs
  ).reject { |a,b| a == b }   # different_pairs
).any? { |a,b| a + b == n }
```

**Blocks in Ruby Are Method Arguments**

Blocks in Ruby are first-class syntax structures for passing closures as arguments to methods. If you're more familiar with object-oriented concepts than functional ones, here is an example of an object (kind of) acting as a closure:

```rb
class MultiplyPairStrategy
  def perform(a, b)
    a * b
  end
end

def convert_using_strategy(pairs, strategy)
  new_array = []
  for pair in pairs do
    new_array << strategy.perform(*pair)
  end
  new_array
end

pairs = [
  [2, 3],
  [5, 4],
]

multiply_pair = MultiplyPairStrategy.new
convert_using_strategy(pairs, multiply_pair) # => [6, 20]
```

Which is the same as:

```rb
multiply_pair = Proc.new { |a, b| a * b }
pairs.map(&multiply_pair)
```

Which is the same as the most idiomatic:

```rb
pairs.map { |a, b| a * b }
```

Comment: Okay the parenthesis make a lot of sense....so reject is applied with the block { |a,b| a == b }, and any? is applied to the block { |a,b| a + b == n }, correct? I think my confusion previously was that I thought the .any? method was being applied to the first block. 

I'm used to code such as someInt.ToString(). Here, I try to convert an int to a string in some other language. But in this case, it appears as if the .any? is not applied to what's before it (like my example), but the code block provided after it? (This is my first time with Ruby)

Comment: You must understand one thing: Blocks in Ruby Are Method Arguments. I've added a section to my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. This makes a lot of sense. This has already helped me out significantly.

Answer (score 2):

The return result of the first method is returned and used by the second method.

This:

```
result = arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }
```

is functionality equivalent to:

```
results = arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b} # matrix of array pairs with identical values rejected
result = results.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }  #true/false
```

This might be best visualized in `pry` (comments mine)

```
[1] pry(main)> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2] pry(main)> n = 10
=> 10
[3] pry(main)> result_reject = arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b } # all combinations of array elements, with identical ones removed
=> [[1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [1, 5],
 [1, 5],
 [2, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [2, 5],
 [2, 5],
 [3, 1],
 [3, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [3, 5],
 [3, 5],
 [4, 1],
 [4, 2],
 [4, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [4, 5],
 [5, 1],
 [5, 2],
 [5, 3],
 [5, 4],
 [5, 1],
 [5, 2],
 [5, 3],
 [5, 4]]
[4] pry(main)> result_reject.any? { |a,b| a + b == n } # do any of the pairs of elements add together to equal ` n` ?
=> false
[5] pry(main)> arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }  # the one liner
=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Each operation "chains" into the next, which visualized looks like:

```
arr.product(arr).reject { |a,b| a == b }.any? { |a,b| a + b == n }
|--|------A----->-----------B----------->-------------C----------|
```

Where part A, calling `.product(arr)`, evaluates to an object. This object has a `reject` method that's called subsequently, and this object has an `any?` method that's called in turn. It's a fancy version of `a.b.c.d` where one call is used to generate an object for a subsequent call.

What's not apparent from that is the fact that `product` returns an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html), which is an object that can be used to fetch the results, but is not the actual results per-se. It's more like an intent to return the results, and an ability to fetch them in a multitude of ways. These can be chained together to get the desired end product.

As a note this code can be reduced to:

```
arr.repeated_permutation(2).map(&:sum).include?(n)
```

Where the [`repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) method gives you all 2-digit combinations of numbers without duplicate numbers. This can be easily scaled up to *N* digits by changing that parameter. `include?` tests if the target is present.

If you're working with large arrays you may want to slightly optimize this:

```
arr.repeated_permutation(2).lazy.map(&:sum).include?(n)
```

Where that will stop on the first match found and avoid further sums. The `lazy` call has the effect of propagating individual values through to the end of the chain instead of each stage of the chain running to completion before forwarding to the next.

The idea of `lazy` is one of the interesting things about Enumerable. You can control how the values flow through those chains.

Comment: Since addition is commutative, `combination(2)` (as suggested by @steenslag) is better than `repeated_permutation(2)`. Also, it might be useful to note that `lazy` optimises for memory _at expense of speed_ (at least in any Ruby I tested in so far).